# Trying to run an SQL file from mySQL shell

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to run an SQL file on a MySQL shell for my university project. I have googled it and researched it and tried all of the solutions I found such as

1. making sure I specified the exact path including a semi colon at the
   end of it
2. changing the permissions
3. changing the directions of the slashes from forward to backward and
   back again and ensuring that there were not any spaces in the path.

No matter what I try I always seem to get the same **unable to open file error**. I was wondering if there are any solutions that I haven't tried. The code I've been using to try and create the table is:

```
source m:/fic1/public_html/Project/code.sql
```

Comment: What os are you using? m: suggest windows, but / is typically used in unix, have you tried source m:\fic1\... ?

Comment: have you tried something like: `mysql -h HOSTNAME -u USERNAME -p DATABASE < /path/to/code.sql`?